# Kummer's Theorem: Understanding Equation of Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, kummer-theory

In Kummer's theorem, it is possible to write ideal factorization as-
$$\langle x + y\rangle\langle x + y\zeta\rangle···\langle x + y\zeta^{p−1}\rangle = \langle z^p\rangle \cdots (1)$$
in which all factors are interpreted as principal ideals, here, $\zeta = e^{\frac{2πi}{p}}$, $\langle a \rangle$ is an ideal.
which is dreied from
$$(x + y)(x + y\zeta)···(x + y\zeta^{p−1}) = z^p \cdots (2)$$

But if $\langle a \rangle$ is an ideal, it represents all multiple of $a$ which makes the ideal $\langle a \rangle$ an infinite set, then how can we write an equation (1) from equation (2)?

Doesn't the left hand and right hand side of equation (1) represent infinite set?

What am I missing? Please explain.

Comment: Note that you could think of $2$, $3$, and $6$ as representatives of infinite sets (congruence classes) in the congruence relation $2\times3\equiv6\pmod7$

Comment: Related! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267777/product-of-principal-ideals-a-cdot-b-a-b

Comment: Well if you have that z=ab, multiplying ideals (a) and (b) is equivalent to considering a*m*b*n where m,n span over every element of the ring. I’m assuming you only care about communitive rings with multiplicative identity so we obviously know that a*m*b*n=ab*mn. Since m and n span over every element of the ring, it’s obvious that mn will also span over the ring, so we can just replace mn with a single variable that spans over the ring, lets call that k. We have that ab*mn=ab*k, which is exactly how we would write (ab), which is equal to (z)