# Product of ideals equals intersection but they are not comaximal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose we have a commutative ring with identity, say $R$, and two proper ideals $I$ and $J$ s.t. :

$$IJ=I\cap J$$

I need to find an example of this situation where such ideals are not comaximals i.e. $I+J$ is properly contained in $R$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290229/explaining-the-product-of-two-ideals  I think that Martin Brandenburg's answer provides some example

Comment: In $R = k[x,y]$, take $I= xR$ and $J = yR$.