# Finding powers of prime ideals from its generators and understanding generator notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I am trying to understand ideal notation with pointed brackets and how to use it.

For instance, if I had an ideal $\mathfrak{a}=\left<2,1+\sqrt{-5}\right>$, where $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are its generators, what does this mean for the format of the ideal?

And how would I find powers of this, i.e. $\mathfrak{a}^2$ or $\mathfrak{ab}$ for $\mathfrak{b}$ an ideal of the same form, (e.g. $\mathfrak{b}=\left<3,1+\sqrt{-5}\right>$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\mathfrak{a}^2=(2^2, 2(1+\sqrt{-5}), 1+2\sqrt{-5}-5)=(2)$ by definition of the ideal product $IJ$ for two ideals in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. For discussions on the ideal product see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/defining-the-product-of-ideals) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290229/please-explain-the-product-of-two-ideals).

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that multiplying the generators will find the generators of the things in the product. I am still confused, however, as to why $(2^2,2(1+\sqrt{-5}),1+2\sqrt{-5}-5)=(2)$?

Comment: Wait, I think I have it;  $2^2, 2(1+\sqrt{-5}),2\sqrt{-5}-4$ are all made by multiplying the elements of $\mathbb Z \left[\sqrt{-5} \right]$ by multiples of $2$ and combining them? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.